# Error in Python and network X - TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, string, typeerror, networkx

I'm pretty new to coding, and am still exploring the endless joys of using Python. Please ask for any more info if you need it.

G is a networkx graph, such that:

```
G = nx.Graph(nx.read_dot('C:\Users\...\myCode.dot'))
```

The rest of my code rearranges the order the atoms/nodes in my networkx graph.I want to convert the output i get from my graph, G, into an xyz file so I can view it with an appropriate software package
.
But i'm left with the error message.

```
write(str(node['species'])+' '+str(node['x'])+' '+str(node['y'])+' '+str(node['z'])+'\n')
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Here's the code below.

```
def writeGraphToXYZ(myGraph,myFilename):

""" Writes myGraph to myFilename as a .xyz file to allow easier visualisation of the                              graph.
.xyz files always start with the number of atoms on the first line,
followed by a comment string on the next line,
and then atom information on all successive lines.
"""
f = open(myFilename,'w') 
f.write(str(len(G))+'\n') # prints number of atoms followed by newline ('\n')
f.write('Atoms. File created from networkx graph by IsingModel.py\n')
for node in G:
    f.write(str(node['species'])+' '+str(node['x'])+' '+str(node['y'])+' '+str(node['z'])+'\n')
f.close()
```

Can someone show me how i can fix this?

Comment: Print the type of `node`. It is a string or dictionary?

Comment: I would be interested in the contents of `myCode.dot`.

Comment: The only indexing happened in that line is `node[xxx]`. `node` is a `string`, not a `dictionary` as you wished it to be.

Comment: You should use `G.node[node]['x']` instead of `node[x]` - `G.node` is a dictionary, so your `node` is a key into the dictionary; to get the actual node, you have to dereference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that exception because `node` is a string, but you are trying to access elements in the `node` object as if it were a dictionary. To check the type of an object in Python, you can pass an object to the built in `type()` function

```
>>> from networkx import nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node("span")
>>> for node in G:
        print node
        print type(node)
"span"
<type 'str'>
```

So you don't want to iterate over G, instead you probably want to access nodes via their key from the graph object directly.

```
>>> G['spam']
{}
```

To explain why you got this particular exception - in Python you can access each character in a string via its index. For example

```
>>> node = "hello"
>>> node[0]
"h"
>>> node[4]
"o"
```

If you pass any other object, for example a string, you'll get a TypeError.

```
>>> node["x"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```